# Attachment download from Gmail

Tags: google-chrome

While downloading attachments received along with Gmail, attachment are downloaded directly to desktop. I want to download attachment to specific folder I have created in my laptop.

Comment: Just change the default download directory for Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change your default download directory in Google-Chrome.
Go to `Settings > Advanced Settings` Under *Downloads* , change your `download location` to wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think chrome does not have an option to download attachments only to a separate folder. I have not seen any such extensions also. The nearest possible solutions are:

1. Change the download directory of your browser - But other files will also be downloaded to the same location.
2. Right-click on the attachment and click `save link as` and select your directory - You have to choose the directory each time when you are downloading an attachment.
3. Use an email program like `MS Outlook` or `Mozilla Thunderbird`. These allow you to save your attachments to a specific folder.